# Кто такое Полкан?

Tags: этимология

Есть распространенная кличка собаки - Полкан. Но что это слово означает? Насколько я знаю, есть дымковская игрушка Полкан - нечто, похожее на кентавра. Но почему оно так называется, ведь в русском языке было слово для обозначения кентавров - кетоврас (видимо, искаженное от "кентаурас")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это из итальянского, Pulicane - «потомство собаки» (©Вики). Так звался персонаж средневековой поэмы, перевод которой послужил литературным источником повести о Бове-королевиче, где впервые на русском упоминается Полкан.

А полностью тут: [Полкан (фольклор) | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Добавлю - впоследствии популярный герой лубочных картинок, эдаких русских "комиксов".

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю, что приведенное выше объяснение официально признано и, более того, именно оно было когда-то давно Фасмером. Тем не менее, рискну предложить альтернативное: Полкан как собачья кличка происходит от немецкой клички Packan, что означает Хватай. Именно так обращается в Бременских музыкантах осел к псу. Такая интерпретация принадлежит не мне. Я просто заинтересовался тем, почему осел называет в сказке пса Packan, и нашел в одном из переводов Хватайка

Comment: Ну предложить-то вы можете, а как насчет аргументов? Пока у вас ничего, кроме весьиа отдаленного фонетического сходства, в пользу вашей версии не представлено.